# Is there a way to combine two different packages to give one result?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I am trying to build a mobile application which takes a photo of a document that has a barcode on it. The usage i want to adapt is: to be able to take a photo of a document and  seperatly read and extract the barcode info,then in the same process save both the photo and the barcode info that are linked to each other, to internal storage or DropBox Link via API with a press of a button. I have two packages in my mind. These are the packages: [camera: ^0.10.0+1](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) (for the camera) and [barcode_finder: ^0.0.5](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_finder).